# Kendo Chart with simple dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

I have a chart with date and count, avg, min, max functions. When I click functions I can get all values of my chart.

I just want to show a simple grid near my chart. I just want to show my categories name and their values. I have been trying for hours but I couldn't do that.

I can show my categories name with this code:

```
$("#ce").html(series[3].name);
```

And I want to show its value near it.

But I can't. Thanks for your help.

Here is an example of what I mean with JavaScript functions:
[Telerik Kendo chart with date functions](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/Beta/area-charts/date-axis)

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    <div align="center" id="aa">
        @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
            .Name("chartMesleki258")   
            .Title(title => title
                .Text("aa)")
                .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top))
            .Legend(legend => legend
                .Visible(true)
                .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top))
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series
                    .Column(model => model.aa, categoryExpression: model => model.EvrakTarih).Name("eee Dosyalar")
                    .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count);
                series
                   .Column(model => model.aa, categoryExpression: model => model.EvrakTarih).Name("eee Dosyalar")
                   .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count);
                series
                  .Column(model => model.aa, categoryExpression: model => model.EvrakTarih).Name("Kapsam Disi Dosyalar")
                  .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count);
            })
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Date()
                .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Months)
                .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false)))
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #"))
        )
    </div>
</td>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".configuration").bind("change", refresh);
    });

    function refresh() {
        var chart = $("#chartMesleki258").data("kendoChart"),
            series = chart.options.series,
            type = $("input[name=seriesType]:checked").val(),
            stack = $("#stack").prop("checked");

        for (var i = 0, length = series.length; i < length; i++) {
            series[i].stack = stack;
            series[i].type = type;
        };

        chart.refresh();
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".configuration").bind("change", refresh);

    function refresh() {
        var chart = $("#chartMesleki258").data("kendoChart"),
        series = chart.options.series,
        categoryAxis = chart.options.categoryAxis,
        baseUnitInputs = $("input:radio[name=baseUnit]"),
        aggregateInputs = $("input:radio[name=aggregate]");

        for (var i = 0, length = series.length; i < length; i++) {
            series[i].aggregate = aggregateInputs.filter(":checked").val();
        }

        categoryAxis.baseUnit = baseUnitInputs.filter(":checked").val();

        chart.refresh();
    }
</script>
```